# keep it inside your body, where it belongs [antecedent of 'where']

Tags: relative-clauses, antecedents

[Bolt](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0397892/characters/nm0261435), a Disney animation, has these lines:

> Bolt : What is this red liquid coming from my paw?

> Mittens : It's called blood, hero!

> Bolt : Do I need it?

> Mittens : Yes, so if you want to keep it inside your body, **where** it belongs, you should stop jumping off trucks doing eighty on the interstate!

Let me change the last sentence as follows:

> Mittens : Yes. Actually, your body, **where** it belongs, needs it. So if you want to keep it inside your body, you should stop jumping off trucks doing eighty on the interstate!

What's the antecedent of *where* in the original version and in the changed version?

---

**Note**: This question originally also asked the following:

> Can you remove the comma before where and make it a restrictive relative clause?

Only after one of the answers was given to address that was it edited.

Comment: Please do not edit questions in such a way as to invalidate already provided answers. Somebody reading the answer provided before you made the edit could downvote the answer because it seems to be answering something that was never asked. I have added a note to your question to provide the original context. Feel free to change my edit into your own words, but leave the original question in some form.

Comment: @JasonBassford Right. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: 'Your body _in which_ it belongs, needs it.' 'Where' is not quite idiomatic when talking of containing fluid within an enclosure, I would say. The sentence reads uncomfortably, but not because of the antecedent position.

Answer (score 3):

> Yes, so if you want to keep it inside your body, where it belongs, you should stop jumping off trucks doing eighty on the interstate!

If you split the relative clause into a separate sentence, it would be "It belongs **inside your body**." So I think it's reasonable to say that the prepositional phrase "inside your body" is the antecedent of *where* in the quoted sentence.

> Actually, your body, where it belongs, needs it.

This sentence doesn't sound very good to me (I'm not sure why).*

Let's look at another sentence with a similar structure. I found one that seems suitable in "[Multilingual Writing, for Example](http://www.annetardos.com/essay_multilingualwriting.html)" by Anne Tardos:

> Once grown up, I moved to New York, where I live now.

Split into a separate sentence, the relative clause would be something like "I live in New York now." But the sentence with the relative clause doesn't contain *in,* of course. So we'd have to say that the antecedent here is just the noun phrase "New York".

Based on this, I assume you're wondering why we can't say the antecedent of "where" in the first sentence is just the noun phrase "your body". And I guess I don't have a definite answer to that question. I would say that *where* can have as its antecedent either an entire prepositional phrase, or a noun phrase that could occur as part of a prepositional phrase. The attachment of the relative clause would thus be ambiguous, as it is for relative clauses after noun phrases that contain other noun phrases.

It's clear I think that *where* can take a prepositional phrase as its antecedent because there are some prepositional phrases in English that don't contain an (independently written) noun phrase—e.g. "right inside" (which historically is from the preposition *in* and the noun *side,* but synchronically is not syntactically divisible and is written as one word)—and *where* clauses can be used with these in the same way that they can be used with prepositional phrases containing conventional noun phrases:

> Each is lovingly cooked on our special slanted grills, gently placed at a degree just tilted enough to keep all that juicy goodness **right inside, where it belongs.**

([Hoffbrau Steak & Grill House](https://hoffbrausteakandgrill.com/brand-new-burgers-and-buns-from-the-brau/))

It doesn't seem attractive to argue that the antecedent of *where* here is "-side".

---

*I can give an example of a similar structure where I have a matching intuition about using a noun phrase vs. a prepositional phrase alongside *where*:

- "New York is where I live now."/"Where I live now is New York." These are fine.
- "Your body is where it belongs."/"Where it belongs is your body." I think that this is not unacceptable to me, but I prefer "Inside your body is where it belongs."/"Where it belongs is inside your body."

Comment: +1 for _Based on this, I assume you're wondering we can't say the antecedent of "where" in the first sentence is just the noun phrase "your body"._ :)

Comment: Does this sound any better to you? _Actually, it's needed by your body, where it belongs._

Comment: In your burger example, _right inside_ means _right inside each (burger)_, and _each (burger)_ is left out for it's redundant. Then, you can say that _where_ refers to the omitted NP _each (burger)_, can you not?

Comment: @JK2: I don't like the idea of an omitted NP "each burger". I don't think "inside" always takes an NP complement; I would say it can be a "transitive" or "intransitive" preposition.

Answer (score 1):

1. I believe you can remove the comma and still keep the sentence grammatically correct. However I'm not sure if that would make it a restrictive relative clause, as *where it belongs* doesn't give us any additional information as to the blood. (Sources: https://www.thoughtco.com/restrictive-relative-clause-1691914)
2. The antecedent in this case is *inside*, with *your body* modifying it.

Comment: Yes, without the first comma it would become restrictive. The intention of the speaker is signalled by the existence or nonexistence of the comma. You can *choose* to interpret it as nonrestrictive, but—unless the author didn't match their intent to the commonly accepted use of the comma in this case—it would be assumed that wasn't what they had meant to communicate. (Even semantically, in the right context, blood, such as at a blood bank, doesn't actually belong inside somebody's body, but in a bag into which it has been withdrawn. So the punctuation makes a difference in those cases.)

Comment: @JasonBassford thanks for the clarification and catching my error. As I'm new to this Stack Exchange and unsure of the rules, should I update and edit my answer to reflect what you've pointed out and make my answer more accurate?

Comment: Only if you agree with it. As perhaps convincing as my comment might be, it's just a comment, and other people might have different opinions. ;)

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question.